# Render node fields in the views-view--[view_machine_name].html.twig

Tags: theming, 8, nodes

I have a view called customfeedview showing contents of a content type viz. customfeeds. 
View Setting are given in the picture below: 
[image: View Settings]
I created views-view--customfeedview.html.twig to customize the view. Code of the file is given here under.

```
        <div class="box prog">
            <div class="col-md-3"><img src="{{directory}}/images/2000px-Lotus_position.svg.png" ></div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                    <h3><b>{{ fields.title.content }} </b></h3>
                        <p>{{ fields.body.content }} </p>
            </div>
      </div>
```

But `{{ fields.body.content }}` & `{{ fields.title.content }}` does not render title and body of the contents of type customfeed.

Please help me in this issue as I am totally a beginner in drupal 8. Thank you...

N.B.: Here I am using show-type content instead of fields as only show-type content only give read-more option in the view page. Using show-type fields `{{ fields.body.content }}` is working fine but whenever I changed it to content `{{ fields.body.content }}` is not rendering the values.

Comment: Educated guess, when using `Show: Content`, try `{{ content.body }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the node field in the view template

```
 node.field_(your-field).value
```

This will print the html tags as well, If the node field has the html structure.

```
node.field_(your-field).value | raw (or) node.field_(your-field).value |render|striptags
```

This will clean the html structure and useful to print the node value inside the view.template

NOTE: using node. instead of content. , because content. will be used only the node.html.twig